# what is the value of an empty cell of a 2d array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

i am kind of new in c and i am trying to figure things out.

my question is, what i need to have in the place of `'/0'` , in order for it to skip 
the "empty" cells?

i know i could do it the easy way and just have have all the .anoxi values in the condition, but i was just curious.
i have tried putting `""`, which gives me all the names (doesn't skip any of them) , `''` which gives me "*[Error] empty character constant*" and
**null**, which gives me "*[Error] 'null' was not declared in this scope*"

```
struct t { 
    char anoxi[10];
    char name[10];
    char gramma [2];
}

int main() {
    struct t array[5][12];
    int r;
    strcpy(array[4][1].anoxi, "+-1%");
    strcpy(array[4][2].anoxi, "+-2%");
    strcpy(array[4][5].anoxi, "+-0.5%");
    strcpy(array[4][6].anoxi, "+-0.25%");
    strcpy(array[4][7].anoxi, "+-1%");
    strcpy(array[4][8].anoxi, "+-0.05%");

    strcpy(array[0][0].gramma, "M");
    strcpy(array[0][1].gramma, "K");
    strcpy(array[0][2].gramma, "N");
    strcpy(array[0][3].gramma, "O");
    strcpy(array[0][4].gramma, "I");
    strcpy(array[0][5].gramma, "R");
    strcpy(array[0][6].gramma, "L");
    strcpy(array[0][7].gramma, "V");
    strcpy(array[0][8].gramma, "G");
    strcpy(array[0][9].gramma, "A");
    strcpy(array[0][10].gramma, "X");
    strcpy(array[0][11].gramma, "S");

    strcpy(array[1][0].name, "Black");
    strcpy(array[1][1].name, "Brown");
    strcpy(array[1][2].name, "Red");
    strcpy(array[1][3].name, "Orange");
    strcpy(array[1][4].name, "Yellow");
    strcpy(array[1][5].name, "Green");
    strcpy(array[1][6].name, "Blue");
    strcpy(array[1][7].name, "Purple");
    strcpy(array[1][8].name, "Grey");
    strcpy(array[1][9].name, "White");
    strcpy(array[1][10].name, "Gold");
    strcpy(array[1][11].name, "Silver");

    for (r=0; r<12; r++) {
        if (array[4][r].anoxi!= '\0') {
            printf("%s = %s\n",array[0][r].gramma, array[1][r].name);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Μπάμπη, please do me a favor, and indent this code. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Yes Xaralabos, @AnT is right. You should be really careful when it comes to tagging. I re-tagged your question to [tag:C]. Now that you learnt it, I am sure you won't make it again. :)

Comment: my bad, ima try to double check it from now on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you got, it you may want to read my [Structs (C)](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/structs-c/), which offers a compact example, that might come in handy<sup>*</sup>.

---

First of all, allow me to question the validity of this code. Consider this equivalent example I made:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct t { 
    char anoxi[10];
    char name[10];
    char gramma [2];
};

int main(void) {
        struct t my_array[5][1];
        if(my_array[0][0].anoxi != '\0')
                printf("%s\n", my_array[0][0].anoxi);
        return 0;
}
```

It will print, in *my* machine:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$ gcc -Wall px.c
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$ ./a.out 
����
```

Why?

Because, the memory the array holds *is not initialized* to anything, so its value is undefined, which invokes **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR**!

We could fix this, by initializing every string, like this:

```
    struct t my_array[5][1];
    my_array[0][0].anoxi[0] = '\0';
    if(my_array[0][0].anoxi[0] != '\0')
            printf("edw %s\n", my_array[0][0].anoxi);
```

Or, as Mike suggested, you could use [memset()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/), like this:

```
memset (my_array, 0, sizeof (my_array);
```

---

Usually we set the value of a variable to a predefined value, which for us, **humans** tells that this cell/string/whatever is empty.

[c](/questions/tagged/c) does **not** know that, unless we tell our program to keep an eye out of empty "things". We have to inform our program what is an empty "thing", especially how to identify it!

Here, you have a string and you check `array[4][r].anoxi!= '\0'`, which is *always* true because the left-hand side is an array, which decays to pointer in this expression, as M.M said.

---

*<sub>I am not writing it here, since the answer is already too long</sub>

Comment: i tried printing them but each cell have a different value, like, printf("%s\n",pinakas[4][0]); prints ! , while pinakas[4][3] prints @.....i can also print them without getting error as just chars and as integers, thats why i am so confused

Comment: Yes exactly, you see, they print random stuff, because the memory is not initialized. When I do `char my_array[5]`, the system allocates 5 contiguous memory positions, every one of size of `char`. I do not know what this memory has, thus when I print, I do not know what I am going to see. However, if I also do `strcpy(my_array, "hello babis");` and then print the string, I know what I am going to see, since I filled the array with something, it is not uninitialized now! @XaralabosNikolaidhs now that I now you got, it I would like you to check my last edit, it might help you.

Comment: ok, so i tried adding values to the "empty" cells (strcpy(pinakas[4][3].anoxi, "Empty"); and so on, and i tried - if (pinakas[4][r].anoxi!="Empty")-  and it still show all 12 names

Comment: @XaralabosNikolaidhs, use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to do that, like `if(strcmp(pinakas[4][r].anoxi, "Empty") != 0)` and tell how it goes.

Comment: @XaralabosNikolaidhs, because you test for every `r` maybe? but you have done only `(strcpy(pinakas[4][3].anoxi, "Empty");`?

Comment: WOW, IT WORKED, tnx a lot

Comment: Great @XaralabosNikolaidhs, but please make sure you read my edit as well! :)

Comment: Or, for us bad boys, ::memset (my_array, 0, sizeof (my_array);

Comment: `array[4][r].anoxi!= '\0'` is always true because the left-hand side is an array, which decays to pointer in this expression

Comment: Exactly! @M.M is right Xalarabos! M.M do you think that I should improve my answer on that, or is it OK to leave it as is (since this has to do with the comments)?

Comment: well you should fix mistakes in your answer

Comment: How in the world did I miss that? Thanks a ton @M.M!

Answer (score 5):

C has no concept of "empty". Variables in C represent actual physical memory locations, and they contain whatever that memory contains, which is either what they were initialized to contain, or some random value if they were never initialized (note that `static`s are initialized by default).

This doesn't prevent you from choosing to *interpret* one of the possible values of a variable as "empty", but that would be your choice, and entirely up to you. You would then have to initialize your variable/array with that value and check for it. Character variables often use the value `'\0'` for this, which should work for you--just make sure you take care of the difference between single characters and arrays: for example, `... if...gramma[0] == '\0'' ...`

There is what you might consider an exception to this: one of the values pointer variables are allowed to take is a value called NULL, which is guaranteed not to point to anything. This is often used to initialize pointer variables but you still have to do the initialization and checking yourself.

Comment: You should probably mention that static variables do get default inialization, but automatic variables don't.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, initialize the array to blank:

```
struct t array[5][12] = { 0 };
```

This means that any members you have not yet assigned contents to will have value `0`  (converted to the type of that member). This is so that later on you can see if the member has been assigned something else by checking to see if it is still `0` or not.

Then you can check:

```
if ( array[4][r].anoxi[0] ) {
//                   ^^^^
```

Note that you must check `anoxi[0]` which is a `char` object.  Checking `anoxi`, which is an array object, merely checks that the array exists in memory (which it tautologically does), not whether the contents of the array are some particular value.

---

NB. The `!= '\0'` is redundant, I think it is clearer to omit it but you could use it if you want.